# Windows Task Scheduler unable to run Python Script, error value: 2147944320

Tags: python, executable, windows-task-scheduler, file-access

I have created a new task, with one action: Start a program. I followed the instructions from https://www.jcchouinard.com/python-automation-using-task-scheduler/

my python script looks like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = 1
```

Under general properties, I have 'run whether user is logged on or not' checked, 'run with highest privileges' checked, and myself as the user running the task. I am an administrator.

Action Parameters...

**Program/script**: C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe (pasted from command `where python`)
**Add arguments**: py_test.py
**Start in**: C:\Users\myuser\Desktop

I tested from the command line that I can run this command successfully:
`C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\py_test.py`

When I click 'run' from the task scheduler library, I get the error 'The file cannot be accessed by the system. (0x80070780)
When I go into the history for the task, I see this error:

> **Task Scheduler failed to launch action "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe" in instance "{6204cea7-bedc-40f9-bc10-ac95b9e02460}" of task "\TestPythonJob". Additional Data: Error Value: 2147944320.**

I confirmed under the executable file's properties that I and SYSTEM have access to it. I tried researching this error value but could not find anything. What could be the issue?

Comment: Note that 0x80070780 and 2147944320 are the same number.  It's an official Microsoft error code.

Comment: Is this still an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding python to your path environment variables. Then make a .bat to run it. Here's how to use a .bat with task scheduler https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.5/python-3.9.5-amd64.exe.

Comment: I already have it in the User variables section. looks like this... var: Path , value: %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps

Comment: Hmmmmmmmm, maybe create a batch script to run the python script then

Comment: I also tried with a .bat and that failed too

Comment: maybe try running it normally first

Comment: ok, so try putting the .bat in the same dir as your python script. Then put this in ur .bat: C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe  {nameofscript).py